# OpenGL "zoom": object clipping and brightness

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I have a simple OpenGL app that displays arbitrary 3D models. I'd like to implement zoom. what I have now uses glScale, and works to some degree. However, I'm having two issues.

1. Any sort of zoom (+) quickly gets to the point where the edges of the object are inside the near clipping plane. Right now, my zNear is something like 0.1, so it makes sense that increasing the scale of the object will cause clipping. I am wondering if there are any other approaches for achieving a better effect.
2. As I zoom in, the object gets dimmer. Zoom out and it gets brighter. I have a light position at around 0, 0, 100. I have very simple lighting positioned at 0,0,100 and using only diffuse.

   ```
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHT0);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    float[] lights;

    lights = new float[] { 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f };
    gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_AMBIENT, lights, 0);
    lights = new float[] { 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f };
    gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_DIFFUSE, lights, 0);
    lights = new float[] { 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f };
    gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_SPECULAR, lights, 0);

    float matAmbient[] = { 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f };
    float matDiffuse[] = { 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f };
    float matSpecular[] = { 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f };
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_AMBIENT, matAmbient, 0);
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_DIFFUSE, matDiffuse, 0);
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_SPECULAR, matSpecular, 0);

    float lightPosition[] = { mesh.mid.vertex[X], mesh.mid.vertex[Y], 100f,
            1f };
    gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_POSITION, lightPosition, 0);
   ```

I do not have attenuation settings, which I believe needs to be enabled to cause the light to be affected by distance. Regardless, I'm not changing the distance of the object, just scaling it. Sure the position of the faces are changing but not significantly. Anyway, I'd thinking zooming in would cause it to get brighter, not dimmer.

This happens to be using opengl-es 1.0 on the Android platform.

Comment: Thanks for the edits @halfer. You're doing god's work.

Comment: No worries. Your timing is most amusing - I just removed some religious and theistic material from a post, so I wonder if someone might assert I'm working for darker forces 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partial answer to #2 is that I was not scaling my normals. In other words, the previously normalized normal values have a greater (relative) magnitude when the object is scaled smaller, causing the faces to reflect more light ... and vice versa.

You can set a parameter,

```
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE)
```

and it solves the problem, at the expense of some extra calculations. the full story is here,
http://www.opengl.org/resources/features/KilgardTechniques/oglpitfall/

(see #16).

Comment: ah, I should've known. That's what happens when I answer questions late at night. I'll edit my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Scaling will change the way your object is lit as the normals are also scaled (which as you pointed out in your own answer can be forced with a call to `glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE)`).  Note that depending on when they are specified, the lights themselves may not have the equivalent transformation:
http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/lights.htm

> A light's position is transformed by the current ModelView matrix at the time the position is specified with a call to glLight*().

Depending on the kind of zoom effect you want, you could achieve your zoom in different ways.

If you literally want to 'zoom' in the way that a zoom lens on a camera does, then you could change the field of vision parameter passed in to `gluPerspective`.  This will mean that you have the effect of flattened or exaggerated perspective, as you do with a real camera.

What is more commonly desired by typical applications, is to change the position of the camera in relation to the object.  The simplest way to do this is with `gluLookAt`.

Beware of the difference between projection and modelview matrices; changing perspective should be done to projection, while positioning the camera should effect the modelview.  See http://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/projection_abuse.html

nb... I've just realised that the OpenGL-es you're using might not support those exact functions; you should be able to find how to achieve the same results quite easily.

Comment: i had previously tried scaling the GLU.lookAt() eye Z parameter. the effect was nothing until some threshold and then the object started clipping. the (apparent) size of the object never changed.

Comment: That would happen if you were using orthographic projection (or a very small FOV perspective, which tends towards the same thing).